# write and read from byte stream

Tags: c#, stream

I have a page where the User can either upload their own csv or enter values into a listbox which then creates a csv (in the background).  Regardless of which way the csv gets created I need to upload that csv to our server via a byte stream.

My problem is that when Im creating the csv I shouldn't have to create a temporary file, I should be able to write to the stream then read it back for uploading.  How can I remove the need for the temporary file?

current code which works (but uses temp file):

```
try {
                string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyHmssf");
                filename = filename + ".csv";
                string directory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempDirectory"].ToString();
                path = Path.Combine(directory, filename);
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) {

                    foreach (ListItem item in this.lstAddEmailAddress.Items) {
                        sw.WriteLine(" , ," + item.ToString());
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                string error = "Cannot create temp csv file used for importing users by email address.  Filepath: " + path + ".  FileException: " + ex.ToString();
                this.writeToLogs(error, 1338);
            }
        }
        // put here for testing the byte array being sent vs ready byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        myCsvFileStream = File.OpenRead(path);
        nFileLen = (int)myCsvFileStream.Length;
```

I have tried

```
Stream myCsvFileStream;
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(myCsvFileStream)) {

                    foreach (ListItem item in this.lstAddEmailAddress.Items) {
                        sw.WriteLine(" , ," + item.ToString());

                    }
                }
```

However since myCsvFileStream is not initialized (because stream is a static class) it is always null.

Here is what I do with the data (byte stream) after creating the csv.

```
byte[] file = new byte[nFileLen];
            myCsvFileStream.Read(file, 0, nFileLen);
            bool response = this.repositoryService.SaveUsers(this.SelectedAccount.Id, file, this.authenticatedUser.SessionToken.SessionId);
            myCsvFileStream.Close();
```

In the end I used `StringBuilder` to create my csv file contents.  Then got a byte array of its contents and used that to populate my shared stream (I say shared because when the user enters their own CSV file it is a `HttpPostedFile` but when sending it to our server via the rest call (`respositoryservices.saveusers`) it uses the same byte stream that it would via this method)

```
StringBuilder csvFileString = new StringBuilder();

            sharedStreamForBatchImport = new MemoryStream();
            foreach (ListItem item in this.lstAddEmailAddress.Items) {
                csvFileString.Append(",," + item.ToString() + "\\r\\n");
            }

            //get byte array of the string
            byteArrayToBeSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csvFileString.ToString());
            //set length for read
            byteArraySize = (int)csvFileString.Length;
            //read bytes into the sharedStreamForBatchImport (byte array)
            sharedStreamForBatchImport.Read(byteArrayToBeSent, 0, byteArraySize);
```

Comment: I probably dont need the read call.  i should be able to just set the return from getbytes to sharedstreamforbatchimport.  but thats for another day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a `new MemoryStream()`

Comment: ill work on this and post back.  if you have an example to save me time that would be awesome.  Im sure writing to it is the same as stream writer but how would i get my byte array.  either way thanks

Comment: @owengerig ie: replace `Stream myCsvFileStream;` with `Stream myCsvFileStream = new MemoryStream();`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I use to write CSV files

```
    public static bool WriteCsvFile(string path, StringBuilder stringToWrite)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, false))         //false in ordre to overwrite the file if it already exists
            {
                sw.Write(stringToWrite);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

stringToWrite is just a string that has been created that way :

```
    public static bool WriteCsvFile(string path, DataTable myData)
    {
        if (myData == null)
            return false;
        //Information about the table we read
        int nbRows = myData.Rows.Count;
        int nbCol = myData.Columns.Count;
        StringBuilder stringToWrite = new StringBuilder();

        //We get the headers of the table
        stringToWrite.Append(myData.Columns[0].ToString());
        for (int i = 1; i < nbCol; ++i)
        {
            stringToWrite.Append(",");
            stringToWrite.Append(myData.Columns[i].ToString());
        }
        stringToWrite.AppendLine();

        //We read the rest of the table
        for (int i = 0; i < nbRows; ++i)
        {
            stringToWrite.Append(myData.Rows[i][0].ToString());
            for (int j = 1; j < nbCol; ++j)
            {
                stringToWrite.Append(",");
                stringToWrite.Append(myData.Rows[i][j].ToString());
            }
            stringToWrite.AppendLine();
        }

        return WriteCsvFile(path, stringToWrite);
    }
```

Comment: can i add \r and \n to a string builder string?  also will i be able to get a byte array of the built string?

Comment: maybe you will need to escape come characters, but there is no reason you wouldn't be able to add \r or \n. (In fact, I use AppendLine(), so I don't really know).
For the byte array, you can do something like System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToWrite.toString())